# Developing code script to create unique value

Tags: php, vba, excel, ms-access

I have very little vba experience or coding background, but I'm starting to teach myself.  What I'm attempting to write and hopefully implement using MS Excel or Access is a coding program that takes a part number (INPUT PART#) and based on a set of criteria creates a unique item number as shown below. I've seen something similar done in PHP, but I do not know how to write PHP.  Based on the Input part number the coding script would need to be dynamic enough to identify the alpha-numeric sequence and then re-format to the corresponding Unique # layout.  I just need a sample code to get me started.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

INPUT PART# *data in input file
GDA-500MA (1) 
GDA-6.3A  (2)
GDA-630mA (3)
GLR-12    (4)
GLR-3     (5)
GMA-1.25-R(6)
GMA-100-R (7)

UNIQUE PART# *converted format
GMC(X)MA (1)
GDA(X)A  (2)
GMC(X)MA (3)
GLR      (4)
GLR      (5)
GMA(x)R  (6)
GMA(x)R  (7)

Comment: looks like youre going to be pulling out your hair trying to figure out how to string 'hack and slash' this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting with `system.security.cryptography` as this is where I started when I started to teach myself encoding and decoding. That could give you a start on what you are looking for

**A couple of links to help you:**
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA

[VBA hash string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717526/vba-hash-string) <- this is what I used

Other than that I suggest you brush up on some string manipulation like how to find specific characters in a string and being able to extract that.

https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-string-functions/ <- this might help you out.

Hope this helps you get started

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into all this information. Much appreciated.