# VBA Collection with case specific keys

Tags: vba

I need to store class items in vba such that the collection can be string indexed and iterated like a normal collection. But the keys need to be case specific. To clarify I need this behavior:

classWaz:

```
...
Private mName As String
...
Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name=mName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(RHS As String)
    mName=RHS
End Property
...
```

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim d As Desideratum, foo As classWaz, bar As classWaz, iter As classWaz
    Set d = New Desideratum '<- The thing I need - a collection with case specific keys

    Set foo = New classWaz
    foo.Name = "foo"

    Set bar = New classWaz
    bar.Name = "bar"

    d.Add Item:=foo, Key:="baz"
    d.Add Item:=bar, Key:="BAZ"

    For Each iter In d
        Debug.Print iter.Name
    Next
'Should print
'    foo
'    bar

    Set iter = d("baz")
    Debug.Print iter.Name
'Should print
'    foo

End Sub
```

The setup is that I have code using `Collection` that extensively uses these idioms. But I realized as I was testing that my use case requires case specific indexing and `Collection` doesn't support this.

I've tried `Dictionary`, but this doesn't appear to support class items. `.Items()` also returns an array, so a different iteration idiom would be needed. And I'm not aware of any way to force `Collection` to use `vbCompareBinary`. Even using `Option Compare Binay`, which is the default anyway.

I can think of a few workarounds; like having classes that had `Collection` typed properties, instead have methods `GetWaz(wazName As String) As classWaz` and an un-keyed `GetWazes() As Collection`. But this would be a lot of work I'd like to avoid if I can.

Thanks

Comment: A lot of reworking existing code. But if that's the only option, I can do it. I'm really just looking for options.

Comment: If you hash the names before using them as keys they would then be "case sensitive" (ie. hashes for "AAA" and "aaa" are not the same.  Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28362053/478884

Comment: @TimWilliams - interesting idea, but not really on option (I think) because I need to be able to recover objects using something like `objA.Thing = objB.Things(objA.ThingName)`. I guess `objA.Thing = objB.Things(hash(objA.ThingName))` is possible but it would be at least as clumsy as redoing the iteration - and there's an edge case of unlike keys having the same hash. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the issue with using a `Dictionary`:

```
Sub DoIt()
    ' Requires reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim d As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set d = New Scripting.Dictionary
    
    Dim foo As classWaz, bar As classWaz, iter As classWaz
    Set foo = New classWaz
    foo.Name = "foo"
    
    Set bar = New classWaz
    bar.Name = "bar"
    
    d.Add Key:="baz", Item:=foo
    d.Add Key:="BAZ", Item:=bar
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(d.Items) To UBound(d.Items)
        Debug.Print d.Items(i).Name
    Next
    
    Set iter = d("baz")
    Debug.Print iter.Name
End Sub
```

Caveat: the `Scripting.Dictionary` is not available on macOS, though you might consider this [drop-in replacement](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary).

Comment: One potential issue could be that the `Scripting` library isn't available on macOS, so if the code is intended to be cross-platform, then this doesn't work.

Comment: Yes that is a caveat for sure.

Comment: The better practice would have been for me to use `Dictionary` from the start, rather than trying to coble dictionary behavior out of `Collection`.  Just to possibly save someone a search, the reference `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` is required to use `Scripting.Dictionary` rather than `CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionay")` as on learn.microsoft.com. This was not a default reference on my Office install.