# Calculating a hash from a range of cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to count the hash value of several range cells in an excel row.
When I count the same hash in the row below I will know if the rows are equal.
Unfortunately I can't do this by simple comparing rows with a function, I need to have a hash tag.

Is there such a possibility (it can be any calculation method like md5, sha, etc.)?

unfortunately I cannot find any meaningful function in the excel documentation

Comment: Why does it has to be a hash? Why cant it be =exact(a1&b1&c1,a2&b2&c2)

Comment: because if the rows are mixed up, it is enough to sort them by hash and you can see which are equal.

Comment: I don't need to calculate hash of the entire file, only the hash of the selected area

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14749855/5159168