# How Does the Hashing Trick in Machine Learning Work?

Tags: excel, machine-learning, hash, hashcode

I have a large categorical dataset and a feedforward ANN that I am using for classification purposes. I programmed the machine learning model using Excel VBA (the only programming language I have access too currently).

I have 150 categories in my dataset that I need to process. I have tried using Binary Encoding and One-Hot Encoding, however because of the number of categories I need to process, these vectors are often too large for VBA to handle and I end up with a memory error.

I’d like to give the Hashing trick a go, and see if it works any better. I don't understand how to do this with Excel however.

I have reviewed the following links to try and understand it:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/feature-hashing

https://medium.com/value-stream-design/introducing-one-of-the-best-hacks-in-machine-learning-the-hashing-trick-bf6a9c8af18f

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowpal_Wabbit

I still don’t completely understand it. Here is what I have done so far. I used the following code example to create a hash sequence for my categorical date: 
[Generate short hash string based using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358955/generate-short-hash-string-based-using-vba/7359753#7359753)

Using the code above, I have been able to produce collision free numerical hash sequences. However, what do I do now? Does the hash sequence need to be converted to a binary vector now? This is where I get lost.

I provided a small example of my data thus far. Would somebody be able to show me step by step how the hashing trick works (preferably for Excel)?

```
'CATEGORY   'HASH SEQUENCE
STEEL     37152
PLASTIC   31081
ALUMINUM      2310
BRONZE    9364
```

Answer (score 1):

So what the hashing trick does is it prevents ~fake words from taking up extra memory. In a regular Bag-Of-Words (BOW) model, you have 1 dimension per word in the vocabulary. This means that a misspelled word and the regular word can both take up separate dimensions - if you have the misspelled word in the model at all. If the misspelled word is not in the model, (depending on your model) you might ignore it completly. This adds up over time. And by misspelled word, I'm just using an example of any word not in the vocabulary you use to create the vectors to train your model with. Meaning any model trained this way cannot adapt to new vocab without being trained all over again.

The hashing method allows you to incorporate out-of-vocab words, with some potential accuracy loss. It also ensures that you can bound your memory. Essentially the hashing method starts by defining a hash function that takes some input (typically a word) and mapping it to an output value Within an Already Determined Range. You would choose your hash function to output somewhere between say 0-2^16. Thus you know your output vectors will always be capped at size 2^16 (arbitrary value really), so you can prevent memory issues. Further, hash functions have "collisions" - what this means is that hash(a) might equal hash(b) - very rarely with an appropriate output range, but its possible. This means that you lose some accuracy - but since the hash function is theoretically able to take any input string, it can work with out of vocabulary words to get a new vector Of the Same Size as the original vectors used to train the model. Since your new data vector is the Same Size as those used to train the model previously, you can use it to refine your model instead of being forced to train a new model.